# Understanding and Resolving Azure SQL Managed Enable Reboots During CDC Installation

Tags: azure, change-data-capture, azure-sql-managed-instance

When I enable CDC (Change Data Capture) on an Azure SQL Managed Instance, it initiates a reboot, and upon coming back online, I observe that CDC is not Enabled. I'm curious about the reasons for this reboot and why CDC isn't installed properly. How can I overcome this issue?

It gives the following error and reboots:|

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the
> server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name
> is no longer available.)

What might be causing the reboot, and what steps can I take to ensure that CDC is Enabled successfully on the Azure SQL Managed Instance without the need for a reboot?

Comment: "*I observe that CDC is not installed*" It might be helpful for us to understand what it is you're expecting to see or observe and what you're seeing/observing instead post-reboot.

Comment: Some more thoughts: do you happen to have a user or schema (or both) named `cdc`? How are you installing CDC (generally it isn't "installed"; do you mean *enable*)? What comes back when you run `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_cdc_errors`? Does the account with which you're attempting to enable CDC with have `sysadmin` permissions?

Comment: there is no record found  after executing above query  and YES account have sysadmin permission